# shopify remix submit in loop

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, remix

I'm trying to do import module for shopify using remix, and in got following function:

```
export default function Index() {
    const submit = useSubmit();


    rows.forEach(async(row, index) => {
        console.log('row' + index);
        await submit(row, { replace: false, method: "POST" })
    });
}
```

and

```
export async function action({ request, params }) {
    console.log(new Date().getTime());
    return json({result:1});
}
```

I can see from console.log('row' + index); that it correctly run through over all rows, but submit function does run just once, no matter how many rows iteration there will be.

Answer (score 0):

Using async in a forEach like that doing might not be working how you're expecting. All of those promises are going to resolve at the same time, if you want them to resolve one after another you need to use a for..of loop.

That said, Remix *will* allow you to run concurrent actions. The problem you're running into is that those concurrent actions will cancel each other out if the data has the potential to be stale.

Meaning if you run 5 actions that all resolve in the same millisecond it makes sense that 4 of those would be cancelled out. The docs explain this better than I can:

> Remix is designed to handle multiple form submissions to server
> actions and concurrent revalidation requests efficiently. It ensures
> that as soon as new data is available, the state is updated promptly.
> However, Remix also safeguards against potential pitfalls by
> refraining from committing stale data when other actions introduce
> race conditions.

There are some diagrams in the [docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/concurrency#concurrent-submissions-and-revalidation) that help explain this further.

The big caveat to everything I just said is that in a real world situation, for example importing data into Shopify, you should submit all of the rows a single object to the action. You should also most likely use a queue (something like bull + redis or Qstash) to split up the rows. This will prevent you from getting rate limited by Shopify and will be a little nicer for your users, since they won't have to keep the tab open for the duration of the import.